# FileName from URL (overwriting)

Tags: android, webview, download

I would like to know how to get the filename from the URL so that it could download into SDCARD without overwriting the new files.

```
int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);
String fileName = "test.epub";
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/"+ fileName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

writing the data to sdcard

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File f = new File(sdcard, "/yourfile");

if(!f.exsist()){
f.createNewFile();
//Use outwriter here, outputstream search how to write into a tet file in java code 
}
```

Create a unique id with using random for name of the each file.